# Defining the Average Length of Business Cycle using AR(p) model

Tags: time-series

I'm currently reading through Analysis of Financial Time Series by Ruey Tsay. The AR model is introduced in chapter 2 and its properties in 2.4.1. The difference equations are explained and then its stated (for an AR(2)) that if $\phi^2_1 - 4\phi_2 <0$, a complex conjugate pair exists. The average length of the stochastic cycle is defined as:

$k = \frac{2\pi}{cos^{-1}[\phi_1/2\sqrt{-\phi_2}]}$

Are the $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ in the average length equation the same as the coefficients found for AR(2) model using least squares? If not, how can we find $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ for any p?

It seems im overlooking something obvious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi: You should estimate the AR(2) using maximum likelihood. It's not quite the same as using least squares because least squares is slightly biased. If you are using software such as R or Python, they both have ML routines for estimating AR(p) models.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, any idea about average length of business cycles using higher order AR models?

Comment: Hi: business cycles are quite tricky but maybe google for "estimating the length of business cycles". I would be kidding myself if I tried to say anything intelligent here. Good luck.

Comment: @markleeds, if I remember correctly, the maximum likelihood estimator is biased as well.

Comment: Hi Richard: You may be correct. I'm not sure about that.  What I really should have said was use an R or Python AR function that builds the likelihood and optimizes over it. I don't think that there's a better way because, assuming you're correct, then there is definitely is no closed form unbiased estimator so optimization seems like the best approach.